# How to exclude specific unit tests in Maven

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven

I am working on a Maven project and am trying to exclude some tests that should not run in the build phase.  However, all the guides I can find give instructions for how to exclude either through command line arguments or with the Surefire plugin.  Isn't there a way to exclude the file through the pom.xml without using Surefire, as I'm not using Surefire to run the unit tests in the first place?  Where would this exclusion go?

Comment: Surefire is the default plugin that already runs your unit tests whether you like it or not. You can change the configuration for that plugin in your pom.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Surefire is the name of the framework for executing tests (it's an abstraction layer for the specific tool). It support JUnit, TestNG and others. To exclude tests by pom.xml, have a look at http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html